# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when adding new data source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, entitydatasource

i am building project and i use entity framework i need to create a new data source to use it to read and write from the data base like this tutorial :-https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html at this step in Entity Data Source Configuration Wizard it always crashes

[image: entity data source crashing step]

Comment: not really the forum for this type of question. However, just to check that you have enough RAM/CPU - no new plugins and failing that you have reset your settings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: There was a bug in visual studio.  I had an issue where creating a data source from an EF based class library crashed VS if the visual design window was open.  Update 2 CTP fixed this but is not yet released for production environments.  (I know this is an old post but if anyone was looking at the same issue...)

Comment: James, thank you for the info

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Update Visual Studio
2. Ensure all the plugins are also updated.

If that doesn't resolve your issue, I would boot Visual Studio into Safe Mode.

```
START /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\" devenv.exe /safemode
```

If it works in Safe Mode, it could be a plugin.  However, if you update all initially it should resolve your issue.  You'll also want to ensure you do have the SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio, otherwise it will fail.